# On return of Ajax.BeginForm with validation error hide a button.How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Ajax.BeginForm in my page.
When a validation error is returned i want to hide a button.
example:

I want to save a name .if duplicate name exists the controller returns validation error.
On return of the error i want to hide the nextStep button.

Any idea how to do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function OnSuccess() {
     alert("Success");
     $('#btnNextstep').show();
 }  
 </script> 
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "PropertyBuilder", new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "divSave",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",       
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
   ...
}
```

---

One way i can it is OnSuccess i will get the @Model but is this a correct way. eg

```
 function OnSuccess() {
     if(@Model.Id != 0){ //where id is populated when the data is saved.
       $('#btnNextstep').show();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to change the status code from controller action (500 internal server error). if there is a validation error and then you can hide button hiding functionality in onError callback of Ajax.BeginForm. For further detail on this approach pls visit http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/07/server-side-validation-with-aspnet-mvc.html . if you don't do it like this then you have to handle any response in success callback (be it a validation error or success). In this case you can opt to always send json from controller action like

```
public JsonResult test()
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return json(new{success=true, OtherData = "xyz maybe some html"});
    }
   return Json(new {success=false, OtherData = "some error occured"});
}
```

and then in onSuccess callback you have to check

```
if(data.Success){
//do something
}else{//hide button}
```